# Flutter is performing a hot restart instead hot reload [Ubuntu]

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When using android studio and pressing `ctrl+s` or using the lightning bolt to perform a **hot reload**, flutter instead performs a **hot restart** and takes around 17-18 seconds to do so.

**This also happens with vscode.**

[image]

I'm using

- android studio 4.2.2
- flutter 2.4.0-5.0.pre.181 (which is a snap app)
- ubuntu 20.04

Output of flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.4.0-5.0.pre.181, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 5.10.0-1038-oem, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I've tried creating a new app from a template but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the following two commands, it now works.

1. `flutter channel stable` I was on master
2. `flutter upgrade`